# Advanced Custom Field не получается вывести кастом филд Post Object

Tags: php, wordpress

В темплейте главной страницы хочу вывести несколько постов, которые я проставляю в кастом филдах   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот сами кастом филды:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код вывода в темплейте главной страницы:

```
<div class="main-wrapper">
        <div class="home-page">
            <section>
                <div class="flexslider">
                    <ul class="slides">
                        <?php
                        $my_posts = get_posts('post_type=slider');

                        foreach ($my_posts as $post) :
                            setup_postdata($post);
                            ?>
                            <li style="background-image:url('<?php
                            $image = get_field('slider_image');
                            echo $image['url']; ?>');">
                                <a target="_blank" href="<?php the_field('link_to'); ?>">
                                    <div class="caption">
                                        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                                        <div class="text-layout-1"><?php the_field('second_title'); ?></div>
                                        <div class="text-layout-2"><?php the_field('slider_text'); ?></div>
                                        <?php if (get_field('details_button') == 'Yes') { ?>
                                            <span class="inverse-button"><span><?php the_field('button_name'); ?></span></span>
                                        <?php } ?>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </section>
            <section class="custom-cols">
                <div class="row home-banners-content">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                        <?php
                        $post_object = the_field('left_top');
                            // override $post
                            $post = $post_object;
                            setup_postdata($post);
                            ?>
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="light-theme middle-height">
                                <div class="image-holder">
                                    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/banners/home1.jpg" alt="">
                                    <div class="hover-overlay"></div>
                                    <div class="image-text">
                                        <div class="date">September 29, 2017</div>
                                        <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
```

Как в документации тоже пробовал по этой ссылке : 
    https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/post-object/
В итоге ничего не получается.

Comment: а что не получается? какая ошибка?

Comment: reset_postdata() выполняете?

Comment: @KAGGDesign да, выполняю, но значение в permalink берётся всё равно с первого поста предыдущего цикла.

Comment: А какой пермалинк вы хотите получить, вы же в кастом филдах не создали поле с ссылкой и не выводите его значение. Вы же получаете ссылку текущей страницы `<?php the_permalink(); ?>`

Comment: @eugene_v тоже верно, но а как получить ссылку на ту запись которую я вывожу ?

Comment: А куда оно должно вести?? Создайте поля в CF и припишите ручками

Comment: @eugene_v а по-другому никак нельзя ?

Comment: Я же не знаю куда они должны вести. На мой взгляд это самое удобное, вы можете их менять в админке, а не постоянно переписывать код

Comment: @eugene_v они должны вести на конкретный пост

Comment: Я в ответе написал, что вам нужно сделать

Comment: По-другому никак, у вас же нет никакой связи между слайдером и постами

Comment: меня интересует не слайдер, а конкретно секция custom-cols

Comment: а что с custom-cols? Не понимаю вопроса

Comment: @eugene_v уже не важно, получилось, спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте поле в ACF ‘slider_url’ тип поля ‘text’. Пропишите туда ссылку и так же как и остальные поля вызывайте в цикле

Comment: Спасибо, помогло